# Objective c: How to disable ESC keyboard function when the application starts running

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I created a small application using objective-c cocoa framework. Here is the problem,  the application will be closed, when I click the <kbd>esc</kbd> button. Is there a way to disable the ESC keyboard function when the application starts running until the user finishes using the application?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the ESC key close the program? Is it default functionality or something you have built in?

Comment: Is your application a single modal dialog with a Quit or Cancel button?  If so, go through and verify that your `xib` doesn't have a key equivalent set to escape.  The most likely cause is a button with that key equivalent (usually this happens with Cancel buttons).

Comment: I created a "Cancel" button with a function exit(0) in it. Seems the ESC button works because of my "Cancel" button. How to make exit the application with only button click instead of both working.

Comment: Label the button something other than "Cancel". Given that it quits your application, "Quit" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I figured it out. :)